# Node.js response API vs. Express.js response API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, response

Both, [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse) and [Express.js](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res) have `response` API.
And it looks like there is even some overlapping between them, e.g.:

- Node.js:

  - [response.write(chunk[, encoding][, callback])](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_write_chunk_encoding_callback)
- Express.js:

  - [res.attachment([filename])](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.attachment)
  - [res.download(path [, filename] [, options] [, fn])](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.download)
  - [res.sendFile(path [, options] [, fn])](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.sendFile)
  - [res.send([body])](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send)

Which `response` API should be used for sending a response (e.g. JSON, files)? In other words, should I use `response.write` by Node.js or `res.sendFile` by Express.js?

P.S. Initially for some reason I assumed that Express.js is now a part of Node.js, which is not a right assumption, of course.

Comment: Which API should be used *for what*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, for sending a response (e.g. json, files).

Comment: Well are you *using* Express? If not, then you can't use its API. If you are, why do you want to use the underlying API?

Comment: I've seen a lot code snippets to solve my particular issue and then I paid attention that in some proposals the Express.js API is used, while other are based on Node.js API, that's why I wanted to clarify the difference.

Comment: I don't know what issue you're trying to solve but I'd guess that the proposals that use the Express API are using Express and the ones that aren't arent.

Comment: yeah, indeed, sounds reasonable. That's why I raised this question to understand the relation between these two APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bearing in mind that Express.js is now a part of Node.js

It isn't.

> what is the reason behind this overlapping?

Express.js uses the built-in HTTP module.

> And which response API should be used?

The one for the response object you actually have, which will either be the built-in HTTP module or the Express.js module depending on if you are using Express.js or not.

Answer (score 1):

The original Node.js API for web servers is `http`, but the Express.js API was created with the objective to make the development process easier.

Express.js uses `http` API behind.
So what kind of response to use? It will depend on your API choices, if you use Express.js or `http`.